# Change text of anchor once it is clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to show/hide a div when an anchor is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

So, when the 'show_hide' div is clicked, 'slidingDiv' shows. But, how can I change the text of the 'show_hide' div once it is clicked. E.g. I want 'show_hide' to read 'Toggle Open', how can i change it once it is clicked to 'Toggle Close' ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it this way :

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q1ub5dvo/)**

JS :

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

HTML :

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">
    <span class="textopen">Toggle Open</span>
    <span class="textclose">Toggle Close</span>
</a>
```

CSS :

```
.textclose {display: none;}
.show_hide.open .textopen {display: none;}
.show_hide.open .textclose {display: inline;}
```

I personaly prefer to keep the text in the html rather than JS for maintenance purpose for example. Your javascript also keeps clean and simple.

Comment: This answer is great; just because of maintenance reasons. Thank you! I like to use HTML and CSS in place of javascript/jquery wherever possible.

Answer (score 5):

Create a toggle functionality for the text as well using the `text()` method and a callback

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt === 'Toggle Open' ? 'Toggle Close' : 'Toggle Open';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lddc5u89/)

To use the text from the anchor, you'd store it in `data()`, like this

```
$('.show_hide').each(function() {
    $(this).data('default_text', $(this).text())
}).click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    var text = $(this).data('default_text');

    $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt === text ? 'Toggle Close' : text;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lddc5u89/2/)

And you could define the alternate text in the HTML as well, using a data attribute

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-close="Search Close">Search</a>
```

and do

```
$('.show_hide').each(function() {
    $(this).data('default_text', $(this).text())
}).click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    var text = $(this).data('default_text');

    $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt === text ? $(this).data('close') : text;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lddc5u89/4/)

Comment: Thanks, but can I just set the toggle close text, and let the toggle open text be set by the anchor text? E.g. can I set the anchor text to be 'Search', and then set the toggle close text to be 'Close' in javascript? I'm asking because I want to have multiple toggle divs without having a separate jquery code for them all; I want to set the toggle open text just from the anchor. Thank you!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lddc5u89/1/ See the problem, 'Search' changes to 'Toggle Close'